# Few Projectproperty and Listproperty fields returning empty values (CrossListQueryInfo)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am running a CrossListQueryInfo and the ViewFields for the CAML includes

```
<ProjectProperty Name="Title"/>
<ProjectProperty Name="Url"/>
<ListProperty Name="Title"/>
<ListProperty Name="DefaultViewUrl"/>
```

I am getting empty values for Url and DefaultViewUrl, although it is returning Titles correctly. Is this some limitation or I am missing something?